# dynamic hair particle stretches while animating the object

Tags: particles, hair

i have a fur ball with a  dynamic hair particle and as soon as the object moves in animation the fur on it stretches crazily. need help to fix it.

Comment: Images and a [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) would help others to understand your problem.

Comment: @Mentalist i tried uploading a file but it says my file is too large to upload, and how to i add images to the post?

Comment: You'll need to remove some things from your .blend and save a version that's smaller. Images can be added from a button that is visible while you are editing your post.